# Vue Component Not Reacting When Vuex Updates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am working on a system that will allow a shipping station to manage orders. I have the initial change and a lot of the functionality working. However I am not able to get one component to update another even though I can confirm that the data is updating.

**putting some code now**

./store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
   greenboard :{
     station: 1,
     incomplete_orders:[],
     complete_orders:[],
   },
   yellowboard:{
     incomplete_orders:[],
     complete_orders:[],
   },
   dashboard:{

   },
 },
 getters: {
   greenIncomplete: state => {
     return state.greenboard.incomplete_orders;
   },

   greenComplete: state => {
     return state.greenboard.complete_orders;
   },

   greenStation: state => {
     return state.greenboard.station;
   }
 },
 mutations: {
   updateGreenOrders (state,payload){
     state.greenboard.incomplete_orders = payload.incomplete_orders;
     state.greenboard.complete_orders = payload.complete_orders;
   },
   updateGreenStation (state,payload){
     Vue.delete(state.greenboard, 'station');
     Vue.set(state.greenboard, 'station', payload.station);
     console.log(state.greenboard)
   }
 },
 actions: {}
});
```

/app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('green-orders', require('./components/GreenOrders.vue').default);
Vue.component('stations-nav', require('./components/StationsNav.vue').default);
Vue.component('green-board', require('./components/GreenBoard.vue').default);
Vue.component('order-card', require('./components/OrderCard.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */
import store from "./store";
const app = new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#app',
});
```

StationsNav.vue

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="station in stations" v-bind:key="station.id" v-on:click="stationChange(station.id)">{{station.station_name}}<br />{{station.description}}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name:'StationsNav',
      components:{},
      data(){
          return {
            stations: [],
            chosen_station:0 ,
            error:"",
          }
      },
      created(){
        this.fetchStations();
      },

      methods:{
        async fetchStations(){
          try{
            const res = await axios.get('/internal/stations/');
            this.stations = res.data.data;
          }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
          }

        },

        stationChange(stationId){
          this.$emit("stationChange",{
            id:stationId
          });
        }
      },
      mounted() {

      }
    }
</script>
```

GreenOrders.vue

```
  <template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md">
          <h3>Green Orders</h3>
          <p>
            These orders are referenced from the Woocomerce system for orders that are ready to be shipped.
          </p>
          <order-card
          v-on:orderstatuschange = "changeOrderStatus"
          v-for="order in orders_incomplete"
          v-bind:key="order.id"
          v-bind:id="order.id"
          v-bind:order_id = "order.order_id"
          v-bind:number_of_items = "order.number_of_items"
          v-bind:completion = "order.completion"
          ></order-card>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
          <h4>Monitor Completed Orders</h4>
          <p>
            Completed orders eventually fall out of the system once their status is updated in Woocomerce
          </p>
          <order-card
          v-on:orderstatuschange = "changeOrderStatus"
          v-for="order in orders_complete"
          v-bind:key="order.id"
          v-bind:id="order.id"
          v-bind:order_id = "order.order_id"
          v-bind:number_of_items = "order.number_of_items"
          v-bind:completion = "order.completion"
          ></order-card>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-on:click="buttontest">
        BUTTON
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

<script>
    export default {
      name:'OrdersDisplay',
      components:{},
      data(){
          return {
            orders_incomplete: [],
            orders_complete: [],
            error:"",
            station: this.$store.getters.greenStation
          }
        },

      created(){
        this.fetchIncomplete(this.station);
        this.fetchComplete(this.station);
      },

      methods:{
        async fetchIncomplete(station){
          try{
            const res = await axios.get('/internal/green-orders/'+station+'/0/');
            this.$store.commit({
              type:"updateGreenOrders",
              incomplete_orders: res.data.data,
            });
            this.orders_incomplete = this.$store.getters.greenIncomplete;
          }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
          }

        },
        async fetchComplete(station){
          try{
            const res = await axios.get('/internal/green-orders/'+station+'/1/');
            this.$store.commit({
              type:"updateGreenOrders",
              complete_orders: res.data.data,
            });
            this.orders_complete = this.$store.getters.greenComplete;
          }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
          }
        },

        async changeOrderStatus(order){
           try{
             const res = await axios.post('/internal/order/'+order.id+'/'+order.status+'/');
             this.orders_complete = res.data.data;
             this.fetchIncomplete(this.station);
             this.fetchComplete(this.station);
           }catch(e){
             console.log(e);
           }
        },

        buttontest(){
          console.log(this.$store.getters.greenStation); /*ATS:DEBUG REMOVE*/
          this.station = this.$store.getters.greenStation;
        }

      },

      mounted() {
      }
    }
</script>
```

GreenBoard.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <stations-nav v-on:stationChange="updateGreenStation"></stations-nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <green-orders></green-orders>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
      name:'GreenBoard',
      components:{},
      data(){
          return {
            station: this.$store.getters.greenStation
          }
      },

      created(){

      },

      methods:{
        updateGreenStation(station){
          this.$store.commit({
            type:"updateGreenStation",
            station: station.id,
          });
          this.station = this.$store.getters.greenStation;
        }
      },
      mounted() {

      }
    }
</script>
```

Here is a screen shot of the rendered code
[image]

When I click the second station updating the store in index.js and then I click the word button it does console.log out the correct station. However the orders do not update based on the station that store has it simply continues to work with the default station one. Now I could set that button to repull the orders but I feel like I am somehow missing some thing I am new to VUE but not javascript. I feel like it might have something to do with a watcher or an action in Vuex but honestly I am at a bit of a loss. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I see you're copying some getters into local data, usually this is a bad idea unless you actually do need a local reference to that data (when the getter value changes your local data won't). Also it seems you're fetching the orders only when the `GreenOrders` component is created, you not handling the case when the station is changed?

Comment: I am really new to vue and reactive development. I thought getters were supposed to allow me to reference data in storage so that it can change. What other method should I do?

As far as loading orders when the station changes yes this is the case I don't know what part of use I need to use to reload these things when the station changes. For now I rigged up an on click event that reloads all this but it is not idea. 

Teach me oh wise one. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was a lack of understanding about how actions work in Vuex. What was happening is that the async call would not cause the repaint of the orders. To do something that is asynchronous you need to use actions in Vuex. These allows for something like calling an api and waiting for that resolution before committing that information to the state through the mutations which are the reactive portion of vuex. This also meant that I had to change a lot of my local data into computed data and return the contents of the storage instead of using getters to populate my local storage.

This also allowed me to then update the station nav component to use the vuex storage properly.

Bellow I am posting the changed files that now work as expected.

/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    greenboard :{
      station: 1,
      incomplete_orders:[],
      complete_orders:[],
    },
    yellowboard:{
      incomplete_orders:[],
      complete_orders:[],
    },
    dashboard:{

    },
  },
  getters: {
    greenIncomplete: state => {
      return state.greenboard.incomplete_orders;
    },

    greenComplete: state => {
      return state.greenboard.complete_orders;
    },

    greenStation: state => {
      return state.greenboard.station;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateGreenOrders (state,payload){
      console.log(payload);
      state.greenboard.incomplete_orders = payload.incomplete_orders;
      state.greenboard.complete_orders = payload.complete_orders;
      state.greenboard.station = payload.station;
    },
    updateGreenStation (state,payload){
      Vue.delete(state.greenboard, 'station');
      Vue.set(state.greenboard, 'station', payload.station);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async updateGreenOrders(context,payload){
      try{
        const incomplete = await axios.get('/internal/green-orders/'+payload.station+'/0/');
        const complete = await axios.get('/internal/green-orders/'+payload.station+'/1/');
        context.commit({
          type:"updateGreenOrders",
          incomplete_orders: incomplete.data.data,
          complete_orders:complete.data.data,
          station:payload.station
        });
      }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

StationsNav.vue

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="station in stations" v-bind:key="station.id" v-on:click="stationChange(station.id)">{{station.station_name}}<br />{{station.description}}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name:'StationsNav',
      components:{},
      data(){
          return {
            stations: [],
            chosen_station:0 ,
            error:"",
          }
      },
      created(){
        this.fetchStations();
      },

      methods:{
        async fetchStations(){
          try{
            const res = await axios.get('/internal/stations/');
            this.stations = res.data.data;
          }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
          }

        },

        stationChange(stationId){
          this.$store.dispatch({
            type:"updateGreenOrders",
            station:stationId
          });
        }
      },
      mounted() {

      }
    }
</script>
```

GreenOrders.vue

```
  <template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!--button class="buton" v-on:click="debug">
        debug
      </button-->
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md">
          <h3>Green Orders Station {{station}}</h3>
          <p>
            These orders are referenced from the Woocomerce system for orders that are ready to be shipped.
          </p>
          <order-card
          v-on:orderstatuschange = "changeOrderStatus"
          v-for="order in orders_incomplete"
          v-bind:key="order.id"
          v-bind:id="order.id"
          v-bind:order_id = "order.order_id"
          v-bind:number_of_items = "order.number_of_items"
          v-bind:completion = "order.completion"
          ></order-card>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
          <h4>Monitor Completed Orders</h4>
          <p>
            Completed orders eventually fall out of the system once their status is updated in Woocomerce
          </p>
          <order-card
          v-on:orderstatuschange = "changeOrderStatus"
          v-for="order in orders_complete"
          v-bind:key="order.id"
          v-bind:id="order.id"
          v-bind:order_id = "order.order_id"
          v-bind:number_of_items = "order.number_of_items"
          v-bind:completion = "order.completion"
          ></order-card>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </template>

<script>
    export default {
      name:'OrdersDisplay',
      components:{},
      data(){
          return {
            error:"",
          }
        },
      computed: {
        orders_incomplete(){
          return this.$store.state.greenboard.incomplete_orders;
        },
        orders_complete(){
          return this.$store.state.greenboard.complete_orders;
        },
        station(){
          return this.$store.state.greenboard.station;
        }
      },
      created(){
        this.fetchOrders(this.station);
      },

      methods:{
        fetchOrders(station){
          this.$store.dispatch({
            type:"updateGreenOrders",
            station:this.station
          });
        },

        async changeOrderStatus(order){
           try{
             const res = await axios.post('/internal/order/'+order.id+'/'+order.status+'/');
             this.fetchOrders(this.station);
           }catch(e){
             console.log(e);
           }
        },

        intervalUpdate(){
          var s = this;
          setInterval(function () {
            s.fetchOrders(s.station);
          }, 1000);
        },

        debug(){
          console.log("I'M THE CREAM OF THE CROP!")
        }

      },

      mounted() {
        //this.intervalUpdate();
        //this.fetchIncomplete(this.station);
        //this.fetchComplete(this.station);
        //console.log(this.$store.state.greenboard.incomplete_orders);
      }
    }
</script>
```

GreenBoard.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <!--stations-nav v-on:stationChange="updateGreenStation"></stations-nav-->
        <stations-nav></stations-nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <green-orders></green-orders>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
      name:'GreenBoard',
      components:{},
      data(){
          return {
          }
      },

      created(){

      },

      methods:{

      },
      mounted() {

      }
    }
</script>
```

Documentation that illuminated the problem: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components

**Conclusion**

To simplify the problem so that it is hopefully helpful to others in the future.
If you are using Vuex you need to use mutations to be reactive. If something is asynchronous you need to use an action and the cycle looks like this.

**dispatch action -> action resolves -> commit results -> vue reacts.**

If any of the other more experienced people on the site have additional input please let me know. Thank you Decade Moon for the comment that sent me down this path.